# Dynamically adding pattern and title attributes to input control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a HTML input control as follows:

```
<input type="text" value="<%= this.CustomerAcctNumber %>" name="CustomerAcctNumber" id="CustomerAcctNumber" maxlength="19" onkeyup="CustomerAcctNumberChange()" required >
```

on body onload I am adding a pattern and title attributes to this input control

```
var CustomerAcctNumber = document.getElementById("CustomerAcctNumber");
CustomerAcctNumber.setAttribute("pattern","\d{2}-(?:\d{4}-){3}\d{1}");
CustomerAcctNumber.setAttribute("title","xx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-x");
```

When i submit this web page, with valid pattern, it gives me error :

[image]

Input control was rendered as expected as follows :

```
<input type="text" value="" name="CustomerAcctNumber" id="CustomerAcctNumber" maxlength="19" onkeyup="CustomerAcctNumberChange()" pattern="d{2}-(?:d{4}-){3}d{1}" title="xx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-x" required="">
```

Any suggestions or comments will be appreciated!!

Comment: is the pattern & title valued rendered correctly in HTML as you want ?

Comment: the first line `var CustomerAcctNumber = document.getElementById("` is abrupt. can you add that entire line in here?

Comment: I have edited my question to correct the first line.

Comment: Yes pattern and title is rendered as expected.

Comment: The pattern doesn't look right to me for what you need. have you tested it elsewhere ?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem. You are passing the pattern value from JavaScript, so it escapes all your `\` symbols which is needed to be generated in HTML. currently you're HTML generates `pattern="d{2}-(?:d{4}-){3}d{1}"` which is incorrect. So you need to provide another escape character next to each of the existing `\` which will result to double `\\` so you're HTML generates `pattern="\d{2}-(?:\d{4}-){3}\d{1}"`. So the line in your JS would become as shown below:

```
CustomerAcctNumber.setAttribute("pattern","\\d{2}-(?:\\d{4}-){3}\\d{1}"); //renders to '\d{2}-(?:\d{4}-){3}\d{1}' in HTML
```

Rest all are fine. Let me know if this worked.